# Display hidden text on hover on a menu with icon fonts

Tags: css, fonts, icons

I am very new to CSS. I'm trying to have text showing on hover under icons on a menu.
Icons are ok and when I hover one of them the text (initially hidden) shows properly but all the other icons move down.
I wonder if someone can help me.

HTML:

```
<div class="hmenu" style="top: 1580px;">
<ul class="hmenu">
<li><a class="hmenu-icon icon-heart-empty" href="#"><p class="texto">what I love</p></a></li>
<li><a class="hmenu-icon icon-map-2" href="#"><p class="texto">my skills</p></a></li>
<li><a class="hmenu-icon icon-monitor" href="#"><p class="texto">my tools</p></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hmenu{position: absolute;list-style:none;
top: 270px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -580px;
text-align:center;
font-family: 'lobster', 'Arial';
font-size: 16px;
width:1120px; 
}
.hmenu li{display:inline; padding: 0px 0px;}
.hmenu a{text-decoration: none; display:inline-block;color: #29ab99;}
.texto {display:none;}
.hmenu a:hover {text-decoration: none; display:inline-block; color: #fd5200;}
.hmenu a:hover .texto {display:block;}
```

I've search a lot and could not find an answer.
Thanks

Comment: add vertical-align:top to links since they are inline-block;

Comment: Although it isn't shown in your CSS, I'm assuming your icons are background images applied to the <a> tags. When you hover over the <a>, its height increases to show the .textto content, and the increased height must be affecting the background image position. Try setting the background-position property to "0 0" on your links.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You'll likely get help easier if you recreate the issue on jsfiddle.net . This way other people will be able to tweak your code and find a solution.

Comment: Awesome GCyrillus, I added vertical-align:top to the links and it fixed it.